# Rhino mocks telling me Arg<T> inside AssertWasCalled needs more arguments?

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

here's the call inside a [Test]

```
_youTubeService.AssertWasCalled(d => d.GetFeedByAuthorWithRequest("Mark", Arg<YouTubeRequest>.Is.Anything));
```

here's the function on the interface for youtubeService:

```
Feed<Video> GetFeedByAuthorWithRequest(string author, YouTubeRequest request)
```

Here's the error Rhino Mocks gives me when I run the test:

System.InvalidOperationException : When using Arg, all arguments must be defined using Arg.Is, Arg.Text, Arg.List, Arg.Ref or Arg.Out. 2 arguments expected, 1 have been defined.

I use Arg.Is.Anything all the time with other types, usually strings, so I'm not sure what else it needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception message tells you what's wrong: ***all*** arguments must be defined using Arg....

You need to specify the argument "Mark" using `Arg.Is` or `Arg.Text` or some other static `Arg` method.

Comment: Just got hit by this, the reason the number of parameters did not match was the addition of a default parameter. Thanks for the answer